How do I quantify the effect of a factor with many levels?
I want to look at the effect of brood ID on fledging success (a binary variable) in a sample of wild birds. Brood ID has ~150 levels.
I have performed a likelihood ratio test comparing two logistic regression models - one intercept-only and one with brood ID as a fixed effect. This indicated that brood has a significant effect on fledging success. However, I don't how to determine the effect size. How do I do this?

A quick Google found an article by Allen and Ye (2008), An Additional Measure of Overall Effect Size for Logistic Regression , J. Educational and Behavioral Statistics.  The article is behind a paywall, but it looks like it might be exactly what you want.

Have you considered looking at the effect of brood size?

You have clustered data. By fixed effects, did you mean you used Brood ID as a regular predictor in the model, so there are 150 parameters to estimate, 1 intercept and 149 deviations? This can result in inconsistent estimates, as I suspect that the number of birds per brood was small and it could not grow with the sample size. Instead, a random-effect estimator is logically sound and practically useful. The 150 broods are a sample of all broods in the population. By specifying a distribution of the random intercepts, typically normal, we estimate only a few parameters, such as the standard deviation. You may find the R package glmmTMB to be very helpful in estimation. In addition to brood ID, you may also want to check the number of birds per brood, nest quality, conditions of parent birds, and other predictors as fixed effects. Once these are controlled, perhaps the standard deviation of random intercepts shrinks a lot.
To find the effect size of a binary logit model, we can imagine R2 on the latent-response scale (i.e., a continuous fledging success index). See Nakagawa, S., & Schielzeth, H. (2013). A general and simple method for obtaining R2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 4(2), 133–142. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x. There is an R package that derives this measure performance::r2_nakagawa(). Another measure often used in binary classification systems is AUC of ROC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic which quantifies how much better we can predict fledging outcomes by knowing the brood ID compared with a random guess. See a tutorial https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/vignettes/ROCR.html. Alternatively, you can simply plot the distribution of fledging rates among all broods to show the extent of variation.

+1. I think this is really an XY problem where the fixed effects model is not really appropriate.

Thank you for your response. I would normally use random effects for this sort of variable, but want to quantify the "real" variance without shrinkage. At this stage, I just want to be able to tell how much variance brood explains in the sample. I was told that to get the "true" variance (if I'm actually interested in the effect of brood), I should use fixed effects. As you can tell, I'm a novice and find this confusing. I'll check out those resources. Thanks again!

Then I suggest you try both fixed and random effects for brood ID, compare the results, and learn their differences.
